# jQuery - select all elements except those which are in element2

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to select all elements, for example `a` tags

```
$('a').blabla();
```

But I don't want to have selected those that are deeply inside of `div` with id `theChosenOne` so `#theChosenOne>a` wont work because `a` tags can be deeply inside of this div surrounded by tons of other tags...

Is there some possibility how to solve this? The way I would appreciate the most is using `:not`

Comment: Could you post some sample markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first thoughts are:

```
$('a').not('#theChosenOne a');
```

Or

```
$('a').filter(
    function(){
        if (!$(this).closest('#theChosenOne')){
            return $(this);
        }
    });
```